# Loopback third party auth not setting $rootScope.currentUser

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

So as the title says, I'm having issues integrating third party auth for my loopback application. I've followed all of the steps in the docs, but seem to be missing something?

I'm using loopback-component-passport. The normal login process works perfectly.

1. Click signup, redirects to oauth confirmation
2. Redirects back to my site, account is created in MongoDb

The problem I'm having is that when I set my $state (route) to authenticate: true, it's not recognizing either the session, cookie, or $rootScope.currentUser is not being set.

Here's the code that I'm assuming is causing the redirect (because $rootScope.currentUser isn't being set).

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      // redirect to login page if not logged in
      if (next.authenticate && !$rootScope.currentUser) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent current page from loading
        $state.go('login');
      }
    });
  }]);
```

Does loopback-component-passport not work out of the box? Is there something I need to do that I'm not seeing? **I've added the proper code to my server.js file.**

```
// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.json());
// to support URL-encoded bodies
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// The access token is only available after boot
app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
  model: app.models.accessToken
}));

app.middleware('session:before', loopback.cookieParser('cookieSecret'));
app.middleware('session', loopback.session({
  secret: 'mysecretkey',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));
```

**Here's a couple of my routes..**

```
.state('account', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: 'views/account/account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl',
        resolve: {
          // Constant title
          $title: function() { return 'Account Dashboard'; }
        },
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('account.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/account/streamers/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'AccountDashboardCtrl',
        resolve: {
          // Constant title
          $title: function() { return 'Account: Main Dashboard'; }
        },
        authenticate: true
      })
```

**Here's my providers.json (which includes session and setAccessToken)**

```
{
  "twitch-login": {
    "provider": "twitch",
    "module": "passport-twitch",
    "clientID": "myclientid",
    "clientSecret": "myclientsecret",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/twitch/callback",
    "authPath": "/auth/twitch",
    "callbackPath": "/auth/twitch/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/#/account/dashboard",
    "failureRedirect": "/login",
    "scope": ["user_read"],
    "session": true,
    "setAccessToken": true,
    "failureFlash": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had quite some issues with the loopback-component-passport module as well, inconsistent and unrepeatable behavior. And it seems hard to debug (maybe it is possible, but haven't found out) because all `passport` related stuff is encapsulated inside the module. Switching over to the underlying [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) module was a breeze. In the end it requires to repeat code a little bit for each service, but my feeling is it's worth it.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you!